# What does perl -pe "s|$PASSWORD|<PASSWORD>|g"?

Tags: perl

I find this piece of code in an open source project. Here in argument passing some non zero password. I was wondering what the following code actually do for me

```
perl -pe "s|$PASSWORD|<PASSWORD>|g"
```

Answer (score 8):

It's a buggy version of

```
PASSWORD="$PASSWORD" perl -pe's/\Q$ENV{PASSWORD}/<PASSWORD>/g'
```

In this corrected version, the shell launches `perl`, passing the shell variable `$PASSWORD` to `perl` as the environment variable `PASSWORD`.

`perl` will iterate over each line of the specified file(s) (or STDIN if no paths are provided as arguments). In each, it will replace each instance of the value of the environment variable `PASSWORD` with `<PASSWORD>`. These possibly modified lines are them output to STDOUT.

```
$ PASSWORD=bar

$ cat file
foo
bar
foobarfoobarfoo
foo

$ PASSWORD="$PASSWORD" perl -pe's|\Q$ENV{PASSWORD}|<PASSWORD>|g' file
foo
<PASSWORD>
foo<PASSWORD>foo<PASSWORD>foo
foo
```

---

The version you presented is similar.

```
$ PASSWORD='foobar'

$ printf "fobar %s\n" "$PASSWORD" | perl -pe "s|$PASSWORD|<PASSWORD>|g"
fobar <PASSWORD>
```

However, the [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bugs in the version you presented causes it to fail in various ways if the original password contains `|`, `\`, `$`, `@`, `+`, `*`, `?`, `^`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}` and possibly other characters.

```
$ PASSWORD='foo|bar'

$ printf "fobar %s\n" "$PASSWORD" | perl -pe "s|$PASSWORD|<PASSWORD>|g"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "PASSWORD>"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.


$ PASSWORD='foo*bar'

$ printf "fobar %s\n" "$PASSWORD" | perl -pe "s|$PASSWORD|<PASSWORD>|g"
<PASSWORD> foo*bar


$ PASSWORD='$x[exec("echo hacked")]'

$ printf "fobar %s\n" "$PASSWORD" | perl -pe "s|$PASSWORD|<PASSWORD>|g"
hacked
```

Comment: It's not buggy. :-) The substitution of `$PASSWORD` in double quotes is done by `bash` (so `perl` receives an argument with a substituted string).

Comment: It suffers from code injection bugs, as now demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `-p` option creates a while loop that contans the content of `-e`. For this particular question, assuming `PASSWORD=xxx`, here's the generated code:

```
LINE:
  while (<>) {
      s|xxx|<PASSWORD>|g
  } continue {
      print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
  }
```

As other people has pointed out, that `$PASSWORD` is perhaps replace by shell  with the value of env var "PASSWORD", rather than a variable in perl code. I put "xxx" up there just to demonstrate this.

Read more about this at: https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-p (Or `man perlrun`)

The "perlrun" documentation also explain each individual options of "perl" command.

Answer (score 1):

It processes all lines on STDIN and replaces the value of `PASSWORD` environment variable with `<PASSWORD>` placeholder.

You can try it out with this minimal example:

```
export PASSWORD=secret_password
echo "My password is: secret_password" | perl -pe "s|$PASSWORD|<PASSWORD>|g"
```

The output is:

```
My password is: <PASSWORD>
```

Comment: That's what it *tries* to do. It actually does something different. Try it with password `foo|bar` or `foo^bar`. (Also, there's no need to use `export`.)

Comment: @ikegami not everybody uses Perl code as their password. :-) Vulnerable -- maybe, but the question was about the purpose of this code in some build script of some open-source project --  apparently it works there as expected by whoever wrote it.

Comment: Or maybe they're looking for vulnerabilities. Or maybe they're trying to find the cause of a problem. No matter the case, it only does what you say *sometimes*, and that's worth saying.

Comment: I agree it's too many maybe. Each one is an assumption made by you, and there are just too many of them. /// And we have a severe case of *under*-engineering